# PHP mail function not sending

Tags: php, email

For some reason, my PHP mail is not sending.

This is my script:

```
$tom = $email;
$subjm = 'Company: Forgotten password';
$msgm = "-- DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL --\nHi,\nYou have forgotten your password.\nHereby we want to supply a you a new one.\nNew password: $pass";
$msgm = wordwrap($msgm, 70);
$mail_sent = @mail($tom, $subjm, $msgm);
echo "$tom <br /> $subjm <br /> $msgm";
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
echo "<br />Your new password has been sent to the email you've signed up with.<br />If you can't find the email, please wait a few minutes or check your spam box.";
```

However, it always gives me "Mail failed", and I do not see it in mailbox. I've checked if the correct emailadress was being produced by my script (`$email`), and it was. So I'm kinda lost as to why it will not send.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the underlying SMTP setup you are using or your server has provided to PHP (ie, sendmail or qmail, etc.).

Comment: `mail` uses server's inbuilt mailing service, sendmail usually. If you're sending emails from your local testing machine and if it's on Windows - then you need to set up mail server first.

Comment: What are you using for your SMTP server? I am not seeing any authentication information in the above. Are you using the Mail class from PHP or Pear?

Comment: Try including a `from` address as well; see the manual entry for an example / how to send additional headers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You are supressing the error with that `@` before `mail`. Remove the `@` and try again so you can actually get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to the comments, I contacted my webhost. They tell me I can't send emails using the mail function to recipients that are not on the domain. I'm resolving the issue with them.

Edit:

I needed to add a From:, and the emailadress of From should be a @mydomain.com address, not external. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply a `from` address in order to conform to RFC. Also the return value of `mail` does not tell you if the mail was sent or not. It does only tell you if the underlying mail server accepted the mail.

For a more elegant way to send mail not only using your local sendmail but by any SMTP server have a look at [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).